# Running findstr on Md5deep result and output only the directories

Tags: windows, command-line, findstr

I ran Md5deep on a directory and all of its contents and outputed the results unto a text file (sample.txt) that looks like this

```
5b402495c9205c49ad7928a9688eec69 A:\Sample_Directory\sample.txt
9v5df4g7h8w5q2c1xz3e0qw6ret23tyh A:\Sample_Directory\sample2.doc
```

now I want to output a new text file without the md5 hash like the one shown below.

```
A:\Sample_Directory\sample.txt
A:\Sample_Directory\sample2.doc
```

I am fairly new to command line and would appreciate any help. This is what I have so far:

```
findstr /c:"A:\Sample_Directory\*" sample.txt > sample_output.txt
```

but this displays the whole line with the md5 hash and not just the directories.

How would I go about doing this?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

From within a batch-file try:

```
For /f "tokens=2* delims= " %%a In ('Type sample.txt') Do Echo.%%a %%b
```

And on the command line try:

```
For /f "tokens=2* delims= " %a In ('Type sample.txt') Do @Echo.%a %b
```